# Error 'Remember to start Elasticsearch before connecting' in R elastic function connect()

Tags: r, elasticsearch, rstudio

I'm using RStudio. Trying to connect to the elasticsearch to extract data. Getting the following error (es_host slightly edited):

```
library(elastic)
connect(es_host="aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com",
        es_port=443,
        es_transport_schema="https")

Error: 
Failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:443
Remember to start Elasticsearch before connecting
```

I access kibana reports.
Please let me know your thoughts re the likely reasons for the error?

Comment: My guess is that you failed to start a necessary external package. Is there a vignette?

Comment: @Trina what version of `elastic` are  you using?  I think that shouldn't happen any longer in the most recent version.

Comment: @sckott, R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09) -- "Smooth Sidewalk"
> packageVersion("elastic")
[1] ‘0.6.0’

Comment: @Trina update to the latest `elastic` version and try again, i think it will be fixed for you

Comment: @sckott, > date()
[1] "Fri Nov 11 07:50:03 2016"
> install.packages("elastic")
> packageVersion("elastic")
[1] ‘0.6.0’
> 

> date()
[1] "Fri Nov 11 08:00:19 2016"
> install.packages("elastic", type="source")
> packageVersion("elastic")
[1] ‘0.7.8’ ; i'll be back in the office on monday and run connect again. Thank you very much

Comment: @sckott thank you,  I connected